Unable to use angular 18 on Tomcat 10
I have created a rewirte.config and changed the settings.xml as described in all the tutorials and no 404 occurs when I open a page. So I think those two are fine and there's a problem with what I did with Angular.
conf/Catalina/localhost/rewrite.config
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/tu/(.*) /tu/index.html

conf/settings.xml
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
    ...
</Host>

With ng build --base-href /tu/:
The page is loaded, but no content is displayed.
With ng build --base-href ./ --deploy-url ./:
Direct Links work, and I can go to localhost:8080/tu and localhost:8080/tu/foo from the browser, but when I try to go to localhost:8080/tu/bar/desc, the page is loaded, but again no content is displayed.
